# How to update entity translations on hook_presave?

Tags: drupal, entity, translation

I need to update a field value on my node when it saves. I'm using hook_entity_presave to get the value and update the field on node save.

But I want update that field in all the language's translation of that node but it's updating only primary language('en') node.

```
$node = Node::load($cid);
if (empty($node)) {
  return FALSE;
}
$node->set('field_ship_name', $name);
$node = $node->save();
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$node = Node::load($cid);
if (empty($node)) {
  return FALSE;
}
$languages = $node->getTranslationLanguages($include_default = TRUE);
foreach($languages as $lang) {
  $node_translation = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($node, $lang);
  $node_translation->set('field_ship_name', $name);
  $node_translation = $node_translation->save();
}
```

Comment: Can I update all the translation at once without the loop?